# The Effects of Magic Provided by an Effective Narcotic

Tags: society, magic, health

In a fantasy world, magic exists, however with a strange constraint: to all but a few, it is only attainable through the consumption of specialized pharmaceuticals. Furthermore, the connection, or attunement to the plane of magic, only lasts for a limited time period based on the dosage. Consumption, however, grants the imbiber complete freedom to perform any incantation known to them, connect with magical objects, et al.

- **What would be the effects of this effective narcotic on the human mind (homo sapiens as we exist today)?**
- **How would an excessive flux of supply affect a society which once had easy-access to the drug (cultural, social, economical)?**

Comment: Hello, and welcome to the site. I'm afraid that this question is not only opinion based, it's also very broad. What I mean to say it, you don't give us much to go on regarding the effects/side effects/downsides of the drug, or the structure of society, technology level, culture, etc., yet expect us to write a small essay on the effect of said drug, on said society. Please read up on [Risk Factors] (http://meta.worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/3206/worldbuilding-scope-risk-factors?cb=1), and edit your question to bring it within the scope of WB SE.

Comment: You should tell us all about your fantasy world. Tech level, societal structure, view on drugs and magic, cultural incentives to do magic vs avoid it, etc. What might be people's motivation for wanting to do magic? Is it a military application? Economic? Healing? Once you do take the drug are there any side effects, or downsides? Literally describe every aspect of your world, the magic potion, and magic in general. Even then, your second question might be too broad.

Comment: Thank you for the constructive comments, I was afraid my question may fall into the aforementioned situations, however I read some help pages and found perhaps it would be okay. I will edit my question.

Comment: Can't wait to answer your new and improved question :)